# Can I raise the CPU usage of a application on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu-usage

I'm using GNU/Octave a lot, and sometimes I want to leave my computer alone doing some calculations while I'm working with something else (somewhere else).

Using the system monitor, I see that Octave is using 25% of CPU power, which seems a reasonable amount of power and leave me enough power to do other things in parallel.

But since I'm gonna leave the PC alone, is there a way I can raise that, even if it means my computer will be unusable in a while?

And if there is a way, is it safe?

Comment: A process will only consume the amount of processing power its been programmed to use.  If the process itself is single threaded, which I am going to guess is the case with the process in question, there isn't much you can do to make it consume more then a single core of processing power can provide it.

Comment: Try using `nice`. When a process start its *nice value is 0*. You can use  values ranging from 20 (lowest priority) to -19 (highest priority).